# compile typescript using .ts in import for node

Tags: typescript, compilation, compiler-optimization, tsconfig, tsc

i have the following file (I intend to use the .js file generated in node):

```
import { someFunction } from './otherfile.ts';
```

how do i compile this? the tsc command doesn't work because my tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

(to be able to use allowImportingTsExtensions I need noEmit)

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*? What have you tried?

Comment: Lin du because of "noEmit": true in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1):

TSC transpiles that without problems, it just doesn't emit any transpiled files, because as the [documenation/announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#allowimportingtsextensions) says the allowImportingTsExtensions flag is meant for situations where you have a bundler to convert the files of your project.

Comment: yes, I already know that. but which bundler do I use in node? I just want an output in .js so I can run it on node later

Comment: Questions for software/library/service recommendations are prohibited at SO. But use your favourite search engine to look up web bundlers like vite, webpack etc. The usually also come with a debug server which allows you to debug your TS code in VS Code before bundling.

Comment: vite doesn't do that, I don't know if that other one you mentioned does. I think I'll keep the .js anyway to make it simpler